# How to set a sublist field value from a form field on edit

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have a Client Script that is currently working that sets the Service Item of a time tracking sublist line from the 'item' field on a Case Record. This happens on lineInit and works when I add a new line.
The issue I have is I would like it to work on the first line. When the record loads there is a line already populated with some data, but does not have the Service Item filled in.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it. could this work on pageInit, or fieldChanged - like have the service item update after I update another line field?

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define([],

function() {

    /**
     * Function to be executed when field is slaved.
     *
     * @param {Object} scriptContext
     * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
     * @param {string} scriptContext.sublistId - Sublist name
     * @param {string} scriptContext.fieldId - Field name
     *
     * @since 2015.2
     */


    function lineInit(scriptContext) {
        if (scriptContext.sublistId !== 'timeitem'){
            console.log('test3');
            return;
        }
        /* {N/currentRecord.CurrentRecord} */
        var rec = scriptContext.currentRecord;
        /* {string} The Service Item in the Body, if any */

        var bodyItem = rec.getValue({fieldId: 'item'});

        /* {string} The class that has been set at the line level, if any */
        var lineServiceItem = rec.getCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'timeitem',
            fieldId: 'item'
        });

        /* IF there IS a value at the body level, and there is NOT a value at the line */
        if (bodyItem && !lineServiceItem) {
            console.log('test4');
            /* Set the line value to the body value */
            rec.setCurrentSublistValue({
                sublistId: 'timeitem',
                fieldId: 'item',
                value: bodyItem
            });
        }

    }



    return {

        lineInit: lineInit
    };

});
```

Comment: I have tried postSourcing as well and that does not work. I would consider updating Service Item at the line level based on the edit of another line level field, like duration.

Comment: You're wondering if this will work via pageInit. Have you tried that out yet? That seems like your best option here since the first line already exists.

Answer (score 0):

The first line (or current line in edit mode) will have to be populated during pageInit.

```
function setLineItem(context, isPageInit) {
    if (isPageInit || (context.sublistId === 'timeitem')) {            
        // set value            
    }
}

function pageInit(context) {
    setLineItem(context, true);
}

function lineInit(context) {
    setLineItem(context);
}
```